# Firebase not recognized while using GitLab CI

Tags: angular, firebase, continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to deploy Angular application to Firebase using GitLab CI/CD.

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like that

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  script: 
    - ng build --prod --aot

test:
  stage: test
  script: 
    - echo Running tests...

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script: 
    - call npm install -g firebase-tools
    - firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN
```

I'm using `gitlab-runner` on my local PC, even tho I got everything I need installed and I can run those scripts with no problem locally, I can't do the same with GitLab CI/CD.

When it comes to deployment stage, I keep on getting

> $ firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN 
> 'firebase' is not recognized
>   as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Which executor are you using? On your `deploy` stage you are not using a Docker image with your required tools. Use an existing one or build your own.

Comment: I'm using runner I configured localy with `shell` executor. I was sure that if script works fine on my local machine it would work fine as `gitlab-runner` too, but I guess I'm wrong?

Comment: In that case it might be related to the PATH. Make sure the PATH has the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install it first and then use it.

- npm install -g firebase-tools